# Simple alphabet scrambler --- usage of vectors

Tags: c++, optimization, beginner

I am currently learning C++, using this book: [*C++ Primer, 5th Edition*](http://it-ebooks.info/book/1256/). I made this program to help me understand the usage of vectors in C++. I have prior programming experience (mainly Python), and this just seems way too messy to be the right way of doing things. If I'm doing this incorrectly, or inefficiently, then please guide me in the right direction.

The purpose of this program is to take user input, and convert it into random letters (yes, I know that there is a lack of support for #'s and symbols, but that does not matter), somewhat simulating a hashing system.

This isn't homework, and it's not a dire issue. The program runs, but I want to make sure (since I'm new to C++), that I'm doing things in a somewhat correct way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
int main(){
    srand(time(0));
    std::cout << "Welcome, to the scrambler: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Enter the string(all lowercase letters) you want to be scrambled: " << std::endl;
    std::string user_password;
    std::cin >> user_password;


    std::cout << "Select the type of encryption you want: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1. Standard alphabet scrambler " << std::endl;
              //Add support for other types...
    int choice = 0;
    std::cin >> choice;

    if (choice == 1) {

        std::vector<char> vuser_pass;

        for ( decltype(user_password.size()) i = 0; i <= user_password.size(); ++i ) {
            char letter_hold = user_password[i];
            vuser_pass.push_back(letter_hold);
        }
        //for ( decltype(vuser_pass.size()) i = 0; i <= vuser_pass.size(); ++i) {
            //std::cout << vuser_pass.at(i) << std::endl;
        //}

        std::string alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        std::vector<char> valpha;


        for ( decltype(alpha.size()) cnt = 0; cnt <= alpha.size(); ++cnt) {

            valpha.push_back(alpha[cnt]);
        } 


        //for ( decltype(valpha.size()) cnt = 0; cnt <= valpha.size(); ++cnt) {
            //std::cout << valpha[cnt] << std::endl;

        //}

        auto limit = vuser_pass.size();
        limit -= 1;

        for ( decltype(vuser_pass.size()) sindex = 0; sindex < limit; ++sindex ) {
            decltype(valpha.size()) vindex = rand() % 25;
            vuser_pass[sindex] = valpha.at(vindex);
        }

        for ( decltype(vuser_pass.size()) i = 0; i < vuser_pass.size(); ++i) {
            std::cout << vuser_pass.at(i);
        }

    }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before discussing whether the algorithm is good or not, there are many small things that you could improve to make the code more readable:

- Your program won't compile with some compilers if you don't explicitly include `<cstdlib>` for `rand` and `srand` and `<ctime>` for `time`.
- It is good practice to always fully qualify with `std::` the names of the standard library components you use. Therefore, you should explicitly write `std::rand`, `std::srand` and `std::time`.
- Don't keep commented out comments. They will hardly help you and will probaby just be in the way. If you need to look again at old pieces of code, revision control software are there for you.
- This loop:

  ```
  std::vector<char> vuser_pass;
  for ( decltype(user_password.size()) i = 0; i <= user_password.size(); ++i ) {
      char letter_hold = user_password[i];
      vuser_pass.push_back(letter_hold);
  }
  ```

  If I am not mistaken, you are simply asiigning every element of the string `user_password` to the vector `vuser_password`. In this case, please use the `std::vector`'s constructor which takes two iterators:

  ```
  std::vector<char> vuser_pass(std::begin(user_password), std::end(user_password));
  ```

  This do what you need and you will avoid having to manually write a `for` loop. Note that it is also valid for the `alpha`/`valpha` conversion.
- That said, do you need `std::vector`s at all? You can as well iterator directly on `std::string` since it implements the containers methods.
- This loop:

  ```
  for ( decltype(vuser_pass.size()) i = 0; i < vuser_pass.size(); ++i) {
      std::cout << vuser_pass.at(i);
  }
  ```

  If you use get rid of the vectors and simply use strings, you can directly output the resulting string to `std::cout`:

  ```
  std::cout << user_password;
  ```
- You don't need to `return 0;` at the end of `main`. If nothing is returned, the compiler wil automagically add a `return 0;` for you at the end. Not wirting it by yourself amy help to document the fact that you won't ever be returning anything else than `0`.
- You could a range-based `for` loop to simplify the latest remaining loop:

  ```
  for (char& c: user_password) {
      c = alpha[rand() % 25];
  }
  ```
- Also, `std::rand` and `std::srand` are kind of advised against in modern C++ since there are safer alternatives in the new [`<random>` header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random). However, the alternative is not *that* easy to use yet.

  ```
  std::random_device rd;
  std::mt19937 gen(rd());
  std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, 25); // will produce ints in [0, 25]
  ```

  Now, you can create random integers between 0 and 25 by calling `dis(gen)`.
- Since `alpha` is not meant to be modified, it would be better to make it `const`.

---

So, let's take all of these modifications into account and write your code again:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>

int main(){

    // random number generator in [0, 25]
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, 25);

    std::cout << "Welcome, to the scrambler: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Enter the string (all lowercase letters) you want to be scrambled: " << std::endl;
    std::string user_password;
    std::cin >> user_password;

    std::cout << "Select the type of encryption you want: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1. Standard alphabet scrambler " << std::endl;
              //Add support for other types...
    int choice = 0;
    std::cin >> choice;

    if (choice == 1) {

        const std::string alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

        for (char& c: user_password) {
            c = alpha[dis(gen)];
        }

        std::cout << user_password;
    }
}
```

Voilà! Your program has been converted to somewhat clean modern C++. Now, all you have to do is to provide more scrambling algorithms and to provide a mechanism to tell the user that they have chosen an invalid option and that they should chose again.

Comment: Didn't you meant to use `dis()` for this line: `c = alpha[rand() % 25];`, otherwise, the uniform_int_distribution is not being used.

Comment: @glampert Right, I overlooked that. Thanks :)

Comment: I believe `alpha` can use `constexpr` here.

Comment: @Jamal, I've tested `constexpr std::string` on Clang and it failed to compile. This is the expected because [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) doesn't have a `constexpr` constructor. But at any rate, the `alpha` variable should indeed be a `const`.

Comment: @glampert: That'd be better, then.  I do keep forgetting the rules of `constexpr`.

Comment: @Jamal It could be a `constexpr const char*` though.

Comment: Very clear, well-written explanation of how to improve, thank you!

Comment: Oh, and iterators are the next section in the book, I guess I should start reading that. :)